# angular ui-grid grid height/rows visible

Tags: javascript, angularjs, angular-ui-grid

I am using angular ui-grid. I would like to set the height of the grid's contents or the number of rows visible. Ideally, I would like this to set dynamically based on the window size, but, will settle for hard-coding it for now. All of the grids in the [ui-grid tutorial](http://ui-grid.info/docs/#/tutorial/101_intro) appear to have the same height/columns visible so I'm not sure this is possible through UI-grids API.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You have

```
gridOptions.minRowsToShow .
```

you can set this to the length of your data. you can   set the row height  with

```
gridOptions.rowHeight
```

You can set the height of the  container with css.

```
.grid {
width: 500px;
height: 250px;
}
```

so you can calculate the height in pixel

```
 $scope.gridheight=(data.length+1) *rowHeight                     **
```

in your controller  and set with the style attribute the css height.

```
style="height: {{gridheight}} px;"   //for the container with element with ui-grid
```

or

```
ng-style="{'height':gridheight+'px'}"
```

**data.length+1  because of the label row.

Comment: A few additional things may need to be handled depending highly on your exact config, but this is definitely the first light I've seen at the end of this particular tunnel. Thanks!